# Ionic 2 Installation Problems

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, installation, ionic2

I'm trying to install the ionic framework with npm. I had some issues right now. At first i tried it with the latest node version (6.8) and when I installed ionic I always got an error with the minimatch version. Now I uninstalled node and installed the LTS version (4.6.0). Now when I run "npm install -g ionic" there were no errors or warns. But when I run "npm install -g cordova" I got the minimatch warn again. Now when I try to start an ionic project with "ionic start test tabs --v2" I get the following message:

```
...
Installing npm packages...
Error with start undefined
Error Initializing app: There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
Caught exception:
 undefined
...
```

$ ionic info

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.20
OS:
Node Version: v4.6.0
```

$npm outdated (in the new Ionic Project folder)

```
Package                   Current                   Wanted      Latest  Location
@angular/compiler-cli       0.6.4                    0.6.4       2.1.0  @angular\compiler-cli
@ionic/app-scripts         0.0.30                   0.0.30      0.0.33  @ionic\app-scripts
ionic-angular          2.0.0-rc.1  2.0.0-rc.0-201610131811  2.0.0-rc.1  ionic-angular
```

Someone know how I can install ionic correctly? I'm using windows 10.

Comment: Try updating your `npm` by executing the `npm install -g npm` after that execute this command to update your `npm install -g minimatch@3.0.3`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well it seems to work now. At first I installed the latest node version again. But then I had the same problems again. But after this steps it worked:

```
$ npm uninstall ionic -g 
$ npm uninstall cordova -g 
$ npm cache clean
$ npm install cordova -g 
$ npm install ionic -g
```

So it looks like the problem was, that I installed ionic first.

Comment: Wow this actually worked for me as well. Thank you very much for saving me from banging my head against the wall a few more hours.